# Get Jira's Tickets from JIRA REST API (version 3) using Postman

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get data from JIRA REST API using this link:

https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search

I have also set my authorization parameters, and at my parameters I have set:

KEY: jql | VALUE: project=EG

But my return at postman is this, it doesn't returns me any ticket's data:

```
{
    "self": "https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?maxResults=50&startAt=0",
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "isLast": true,
    "values": []
}
```

**How can I get the Jira cards data?**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the JIRA REST API v3 docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get), I see an Issues Search endpoint at `https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search`. This is different from the URL you're trying - it doesn't have `/project` in the URL.

Try setting the `jql` parameter to `project = EG` for this API like so:

`https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=project%20%3D%20EG`